# How to I exclude all users in a AD group from People Search?

Tags: search, enterprise-search, search-scope

I have a group of people that we do not want to show up in people search. All of these individuals are part of a certain AD group. They all also have a consistent AD field (their job title is all the same). What is the best way to exclude these individuals from people search in 2013?

Comment: check this one, one answer is excluding it from User profile and other is creating search scope...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24053/exluding-some-users-from-search

Comment: Waqas has the answer, to pile on, do you want them to have a Profile? If not them add an import filter that excludes them.